# Analog equivalent for transition width in Digital radios

Tags: digital-filters, gnuradio

I have started off with GNUradio and I am not sure if I understand the transition width parameter available in GNU radio companion filter blocks .

As per online documentation transition width of a digital filter is the frequency difference between the cutoff frequency of the passband and the start frequency of the stop band.

What does the stop band mean? Does it have an analogue for Analog filters?

I suspect that the stop band is a concept specific to digital filters and does not have an Analog equivalent. If this is the case, then what is the origin for this difference between Analog and digital filters?

Comment: the terms “stop band”, “pass band” are common to digital and analog filters and have a great deal of equivalence.  Voltages come out of analog filters while numbers that often correspond to voltages come out of digital filters. your suspension is erroneous.  The term “boy band” is unrelated to either analog or digital filters, just in case that your suspect so.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz not sure what you mean by Boy Band and google is not helping. Could you describe what Stop band would mean for an Analog Low pass filter? If I am correct, an analog filter is described completely by its passband gain and its cutoff/3dB frequency

Comment: I see your point but a high pass filter has a low pass stop band. Even an analog low pass filter has will have a stop band rejection specification.

Comment: Boy band https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_band

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_filter for the explicit use of the term stop  band with an analog filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_filter

for an analog filter where there is a stop band specification.

There are digital filters that are based on analog prototypes including the butterworth, elliptic, and caur types.

One can typically match an IIR digital filter with an analog filter.

Linear phase FIR filters are the big difference between analog and digital filters.

The strongest argument for equivalence is that with appropriate A/D and D/A  converters, one can in theory substitute an analog for a digital filter or vice versa in a system.

Each type has advantages and disadvantages or put another way have different trade spaces.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the transition width is a measure of roll-off (or Order of filter)? Higher the transition width, lower the roll-off

Comment: As long as you use the term "correct" so that it doesn't exclude other correct interpretations, yes, I would say that you are correct.